# Google Pay - Callbacks on Shipping Address or Shipping Method Change

Tags: android, google-pay

1. *Is there a way where we can get callbacks in whenever user changes it's shipping address or shipping method in Google Pay Android SDK?*
2. *Is there a way where we can get shipping address before showing Google Pay Sheet? That is required to fetch respective shipping Options available for that shipping address*

```
registerForActivityResult(TaskResultContracts.GetPaymentDataResult()) { taskResult -> 
    when (taskResult.status.statusCode) {
       //.. Receive callback whenever full payment is done
    }
}
```

I see that Google Web API has [onPaymentDataChanged](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/client#onPaymentDataChanged) whenever `OFFER`, `SHIPPING_ADDRESS` Or `SHIPPING_OPTION` is changed. But I don't see any similar callbacks in Android SDK other than above where I am not receiving any callbacks. Infact I don't see direct way of adding ShippingOptions as well in Android SDK which I added by referring to Web API [ShippingOptionParameters](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#ShippingOptionParameters)

> Referring to `com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:19.3.0`

Trying with `WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_TEST` as Production access it not yet available.

Answer (score 0):

Your observations are correct. The Google Pay API on Android currently does not support callbacks.

Comment: Hi, I will not get any callbacks from Google Pay on Android even on Production environment like Shipping Address, Shipping Option cause those information are required to change the total price? I thought it might be due to Test Environment.

Comment: correct. those callbacks are currently only available on the web.

Comment: Do we have any request raise on google groups or anywhere?

Comment: the team is already aware and is looking into it...

Comment: Is there any reference or issue raised on google groups or github? It would be much better if you can provide a reference as it will be easier to explain peers.

Comment: Raised a issue on issuetracker.google.com. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/331369810